# Suggest best alternative for JSch tool or jar for SSH communication

Tags: ssh, jsch

We are using the JSch jar in our application to communicate with server. If we see JSch is not getting enhanced or changed, the last release of JSch was done almost 4 years back. Since there is no activity at JSch, and no one is responding over emails or on their SouceForge ticket, we are thinking to replace the JSch with some other tool that supports SSH2 and/or later.
Can someone please suggest few best alternatives for JSch, that can be used to perform the SSH operations.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I found few more as alternatives like apache sshd - https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd and hierynomus: https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj. We are exploring these and many more.

Answer (score 2):

There is a jsch fork at https://github.com/mwiede/jsch which is actively maintained.